# C# XML Deserialize StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, stack-overflow

im trying to read ubl-despatch type file.

```
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(item);
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DespatchAdviceType));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            var despatch = (DespatchAdviceType)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            return despatch;
```

On the 3rd line execute it throws stackoverflow exception, and when im inspect on the 2nd line 'reader' object it show ReadTimeout and Writetimeout exceptions. How can solve this problem?

Comment: How large is the memory stream?   How long does it take before the exception occurs?  Make sure the memory stream postiion is set to zero after filling and before deserialing.  When deserializing open up the Task Manager and check how much memory is being used.  You may be using swap memory space if all the memory on machine is being used which may cause a timeout.

Comment: It's **byte[90994]**. I checked the memorystream and its set to position 0, it's not take much time to threw exception, can't see any memory usage on the task manager. And inspected ms and saw `ReadTimeout: 'ms.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
WriteTimeout: 'ms.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' `

Comment: And I want to add something too, we have a same function for deserialize INVOICE it's working nicely with no problem. In that function our item got 5000 byte. But in DESPATCH, item gets 90000 byte is it can be the problem?

Comment: XML Deserialize errors are very hard to debug.  I normally go into the classes and comment out all the properties except one.  Then see if I get any errors.  Then slowly uncomment the properties to find the one causing the issue.  Since it is working in the Invoice I suspect the data is slightly different in the current code.  Probably a property that is not being used in the Invoice data.

Comment: Yea, we got data from server and convert to our system. It might be the Model problem. I'm trying to create DESPATCH Type item and fill props, i get Stackoverflow error again. I've auto-generated the my model from XSD to C# class. Something might be wrong with the converting. So annoying to find errors when a newbie coder with huge projects...

Comment: The error messages for deserialize are not very good.  That is why I'm recommending to comment out properties in the classes to isolate the error.

Comment: I have solve the problem its about the XSD to C# Class. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: You must dispose of objects `MemoryStream` and `StreamReader`. Wrap them in a `using` construction.